# Why is it normal for render to be called in both the controller and in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rendering

The Rails guide [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) gives examples of render being used in both the controller and the view.

The section [Rendering by default ...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) mentions that rendering is called by default. The section [Using render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) gives an example of `render` being called within a controller:

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update(book_params)
    redirect_to(@book)
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

The section [Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) gives an example of render being used within the view, for example to use partials.

```
<%= render "menu" %>
```

Neither the cases of render being used in controller, nor the case of render being used in the view, strike me as illogical. But what's confusing me is that I thought one of the major concepts of Rails is model view controller separation, which means giving separate responsibilities to the model, view, and controller.

Why is it normal for render to be called in both the controller and in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that if used properly, when render is used in a view, it should be primarily as an organization/structural tool in order to make the code for the view more understandable and readable.

When used in a controller, it's defining the entry point into the view and is the primary association between the action in the controller and the view.

The difference is subtle.